# Fatal error: Call to undefined function: MDB2_Driver_MYSQL::getAll()

Tags: php, mysql, pear, mdb2

I am upgrading a site from Fedora 14, PHP4, and PEAR DB to Fedora 16, PHP 5.4 and PEAR MDB2 2.5.0b3, and I am getting the error

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function: MDB2_Driver_MYSQL::getAll(). in /usr/share/php/MDB2.php on line 1892

Obviously, I've checked line 1892 of the MDB2.php file, and it contains the error reporting code for the `__call` magic method (allows you to call a specific function by passing it into `__call`)

I have checked for usages of `__call`, and there don't seem to be any. Likewise, when I try to find where `MDB2_Driver_MYSQL` is coming from, the only place it is even mentioned is in MDB2.php (as a comment about the driver for MySQL), in the class declaration (`class MDB2_Driver_mysql extends MDB2_Driver_Common`), and the description title in the .xml file.

I have manually included the `/usr/share/php/MDB2/Extended.php` file in the file where the `MDB2_Driver_mysql` class is defined, and that didn't help (not that this would have been a permanant fix...)

Has anyone encountered this error, and if so, what did you do to fix it? Google has proved nearly useless, as the only place it is [specifically mentioned](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?462193-PEAR-MDB2-Error) doesn't really deal with fixing it.

Comment: Have you seen this page: http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.database.mdb2.faq.php ?

Answer (score 1):

change getAll() in your class, to queryAll(), cause there some difference between DB & MDB2, and the same with getOne, getRow - they all changed to queryOne, queryRow. Here you can read about it http://www.phpied.com/db-2-mdb2/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you load the extended module in your code prior to making a query, similar to below:

```
$db->loadModule('Extended');
```

Comment: Between the comment by Raffael above and this here, I attempted to load the extended module in a variety of ways, none of which made any difference (even when loaded as part of the MDB2::connect function).

The weird thing is, the getAll call works with MDB2, just not with MDB2_Driver_MYSQL